# Column not taking all available space from it's parent Column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

```
Column(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Green)
) {
     Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Red)
     ) {}
}
```

This child `Column` is not taking any space from it's parent Column

I want this column to fill the full available space

Any ideas about how to do this?

I am trying to make a Column child fill all the space in it's parent Column
But the result is that the child Column is not taking any space

Comment: Can you please provide more code? Maybe the entire Composable? I tried it inside a Surface directly inside the setContent{} method in the Activity and it worked fine.

Comment: This is the code inside the setConent, i dont use any surface

Comment: Then try with surface

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an image

From your code you can see that the child column fills the parent column

[image]